# What's the differences between EntityState.Added and Add()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud

I'm recently using this to add entity EF to my DB:

```
ctx.Entry(payment).State = payments.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
```

Instead of the common:

```
ctx.Payments.Add(payments);
```

The second is nice because I can choose if add or delete.

What's the real difference between the first and the second approch? And why there isn't a straightforward for update item? Such as:

```
ctx.Payments.Update(payments);
```

Which will "mirror" the `EntityState.Modified` one?

This is the code I'm using, setting a `ViewModel` from my `MVC Action/Controller` to my `EF` context:

```
IList<Payments> newPayments = activityViewModel.Payments.Select(p => mapper.Map<PaymentViewModel, Payments>(p)).ToList();

foreach (var payments in newPayments)
{
    ctx.Entry(payments).State = payments.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
    ctx.Payments.Add(payments);
}

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: With plain EF, you almost never need to set the state to `EntityState.Modified`: loading an entity and modifying its properties is enough to have that automatically detected. Explicitly setting the state to `EntityState.Modified` is probably necessary to work around something the rest of your code does, like detaching entities from one context and attaching them to another. Can you give details on why it's needed in your case?

Comment: @hvd: yes I'm passing from an MVC app `ViewModel` to my Entity Model. I've updated the question with the main scenario.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between adding a detached entity by setting its state vs. calling `Add`.

You can see in [`InternalEntityEntry.cs`](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/aspnet/EntityFramework6/src/EntityFramework/Internal/EntityEntries/InternalEntityEntry.cs) (wrapped by `DbEntityEntry`) that setting the state to `Added` just ends up calling `InternalSet.Add`. You can see in [`` DbSet`.cs ``](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/aspnet/EntityFramework6/src/EntityFramework/DbSet%60.cs) that calling `Add` also just ends up calling `InternalSet.Add`. They differ a bit in their preconditions, but in your case, the preconditions of both are met.

The nice part about the first approach, in your case, is that the same bit of code can either add an entity, or attach it and mark it as modified. As you noted, there is no single-method alternative for setting the state to `Modified`.

> The second is nice because I can choose if add or delete.

You can also set the state to `Deleted`, so that is not an advantage of either over the other.

> And why there isn't a straightforward for update item?

Likely because the only use case for it is when you're doing something strange, from EF perspective. Detaching, serialising, modifying, de-serialising and re-attaching entities may be the norm in your framework, but from EF perspective, those are advanced low-level operations with a somewhat enlarged risk of things going wrong. For instance, when your model contains any modifiable property also used for concurrency checks, the fact that your serialisation-deserialisation loses the property's original value means that the concurrency check is sure to fail.